# Bouncing ball physics

Tags: kinematics, collision, projectile

Do we generally  ignore energy loss in kinematics when the ball ,falling under gravity , is bouncing back.Because below graph shows that Ball got the maximum velocity with which it was thrown earlier,almost instantly[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you ask "do we generally ignore..." I assume you mean in solving simple text book problems.  If this is not the case you need to make this clear in your question.

A lot is being ignored based on the plot you provided.  For example air resistance, which would reduce the total mechanical energy and cause a reduction in max velocity (and/or max speed).

The bouncing is a collision.  Collisions in general result in (1) deformation of the objects colliding, (2) sound when there is an atmosphere, (3) slipping of the contact surfaces etc, just to name a few.  As a consequence of this energy is lost in general.  We consider an ideal situation referred to as an elastic collision.

"An elastic collision is a collision in which there is no net loss in kinetic energy in the system as a result of the collision. Both momentum and kinetic energy are conserved quantities in elastic collisions."

In your bouncing ball example it seems that one has assumed that the collision between the ball and the ground is elastic.  If you assumed the more realist case of an inelastic collision you would need assume a energy loss amount with each bounce, dE, and with each bounce the speed with which the ball leaves the ground is slightly less than the speed with which it hit the ground.  In that case each segment of the velocity graph would get smaller and smaller.

This does not explain the discontinuity in the graph.  This is due to the assumption that the collision is "instantaneous".  In reality the ball will remain in contact with the ground for a few milliseconds or less.  So there would be a rapid deceleration and acceleration leading to the sudden jump in v.

How close the assumption seems to be valid depends on the materials of each object.  If they are very close to "ideally" rigid or elastic you can assume that they will rebound with kinetic energy conserved.  In real life no such material exists (it is an idealization).

In short, YES, we do sometimes assume the interaction of the ball and ground is elastic and ignore energy loss.  It all depends on the context.